# Apache Solr apply facets on query results

Tags: post, solr, guzzle, facet, faceted-search

I have a large index and my user can only view some results, but if I perform a query with `facet=on` I get all the index facets, not only the facets of the query results. I'm using Guzzle in Laravel and I need to use post instead of get due to a very long query string, so I use the form parameter "q" to query Solr and the faceting is appended to url:

**Query Params Example**

```
$searchQuery = [
  "q" => "({!terms f=isbn_s}9788808440877,9788808342010,9788808820914,9788808504005, ...) AND (title_s:**)"
  "wt" => "json"
  "indent" => true
  "facet" => "on"
  "rows" => 9
  "sort" => "title_s asc"
  "start" => 0
  "f.subjects_ss.facet.mincount" => 0
  "f.year_ss.facet.mincount" => 0
  "f.authors_ss.facet.mincount" => 0
]
```

**Query Url Example**

```
$url = env('BASE_URL') . "/select?facet.field=subjects_ss&facet.field=year_ss&facet.field=authors_ss"
```

**Guzzle POST request**

```
$request = $client->request("POST", $url, [
  'headers' => [
    'Content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Accept' => 'application/json'
   ],
  'form_params' => $searchQuery
]);
```

An Example of the results I have is:

```
"facets": {
   "subjects": {
     "math": 35,
     "english": 24,
     "italian": 0,
     "physics": 0
  }
}
```

But I want something like this:

```
"facets": {
   "subjects": {
     "math": 35,
     "english": 24
  }
}
```

It is possible? I need to use `mincount=0` in facet fields to display all the facets to the user (the empty too), but I don't want to display facets that are not related to the "base" query

**EDIT**

To clarify: I want to perform a query with `facet.mincount = 1` and on the results subset I want a new query with `facet.mincount = 0`. the first query is the "base" query, the results subset is to be considered as a new index to search from

Comment: The facets that come back in the Solr response are calculated from your initial query. What do you mean by `I don't want to display facets that are not related to the "base" query` ?

Comment: as "base" query I mean the subset of docs found by the query. The flow I imagine is: inital query -> faceting on found docs with mincount = 0 -> next queries

Comment: When you set `mincount = 0`, you're telling Solr that you want tokens returned even if they're not present in any documents matching your query. I'm not sure why you'd want that based on your example - can you show the use case for having mincount = 0?

Comment: It's a corner-case, I want to perform a query with `facet.mincount = 1` and on the results subset I want a new query with `facet.mincount = 0`. the first query is the "base" query, the results subset is to be considered as a new index